# Unitor identities for bicategories

Tags: ct.category-theory, 2-categories

In the standard definition of a bicategory, the unitors are required to satisfy the 'triangle identity'

[image]

for any composable $1$-cells $f:Y\to Z,gX\to Y$. But it seems like we also want

[image]

to commute for any $1$-cell $f:X\to Y$. (apologies for notational differences between diagrams, they're from two different note files. $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ are both just associators)

> Does this pentagon commuting follow from the triangle identities? Does this pentagon commuting imply the triangle identities?

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: This pentagon must follow from the usual definition of bicategory; Lemma 2.2 here may help you prove that: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+category#other_coherence_conditions

Comment: @JohnBaez Much appreciated John.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw the unitor from $(1_Y \circ f) \circ 1_X$ to $1_Y \circ f$, splitting your pentagon into a triangle and a square.  The square is a naturality square, so it commutes.  The triangle is an instance of the dual form of Lemma 2.2 at the [link](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+category#other_coherence_conditions) that John provided.

Comment: Thank you Mike.